# eclipse java editor: how to replace 3 spaces with a tab?

Tags: eclipse, replace, tabs

Eclipse, in the find and replace dialog:

replace 3 spaces with one tab (\t). Not working.
\t is not regarded as tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you copy a tab character from a text editor and paste it into the *Replace with* field or you enter `\t` and **check the *Regular expressions* option**.